# oAuth with Scribe for LinkedIn - accessToken issues

Tags: java, oauth, linkedin-api, scribe

I'm using scribe for logging into LinkedIn in my application.

I would like to know if there is a way to automate the process of getting accessToken so that the user doesn't have to enter the Verifier token.

Possible? 
If yes, may i get a little help with the same?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the browser redirected to a url of your choice, if you provide it via the `callback` method of the `ServiceBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in the new version of scribe, where do i mention the usage of callback feature?
By default, it gives me a link that I'll have to visit manually (OOB it is).

Answer (score 2):

You can add the callback to the ServiceBuilder in the current version of Scribe like this:

```
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                        .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
                        .apiKey(SystemVariables.LINKEDINAPIKEY)
                        .apiSecret(SystemVariables.LINKEDINSECRETKEY)
                        .callback("YOUR_CALLBACK_URL_HERE")
                        .build();
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it throws an exception. I am following the same paradigm for a provided [non-OOB sample](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/cafa2fd69f70bfbf81324c83528b196ca7c14998/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/LiveExample.java): `
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
        .apiKey(key)
        .apiSecret(secret)
        .callback(callback)
        .build();
String url = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);`

Comment: Doing it this way: `service.getAuthorizationUrl(service.getRequestToken())` does not work either because the URL provided does not contain the call back URL.